# NoClassDefFoundError when creating non-final non-static classes

Tags: android, gradle, classpath

I am getting the following exception when trying to use the code from Andriod-SocialButtons project (https://github.com/championswimmer/Android-SocialButtons):

```
I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<in.championswimmer.libsocialbuttons.BtnSocial>
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: in.championswimmer.libsocialbuttons.BtnSocial
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:272)
    at XXX.onCreate(XXXActivity.java:76)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
Class c;
c = in.championswimmer.libsocialbuttons.Utils.class;
c = in.championswimmer.libsocialbuttons.BuildConfig.class;
c = in.championswimmer.libsocialbuttons.BtnSocial.class;
c = in.championswimmer.libsocialbuttons.SocialFab.class;
```

The first 3 lines in this snippet execute fine but I try to access the BtnSocial or SocialFab classes it throws NoClassDefFoundError.

It might be relevant that BtnSocial and SocialFab classes don't contain any static or final fields or methods.

I am using Android Studio to develop & run my application

This is my project `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

and my app's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

android {
    ...
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXX"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 9
        versionName "2.4"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
    buildTypes {
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.github.championswimmer:Android-SocialButtons:1.5.0'
    ...
}
```

I am following Android-SocialButtons's docs exactly: https://github.com/championswimmer/Android-SocialButtons/blob/master/README.md . What am I dong wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `jitpack` in project level build file, not in app level

update your project `build.gradle` to

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you removed the jitpack.io from app.build.gradle file and tried clean rebuild project?

Comment: Yes I did that.